# Windows Server Hyper-V Core 2019 - Host Hogging 100% RAM

Tags: windows, memory, virtualization, windows-server-2016

I have a server which has Windows Server Data Centre 2019 installed as a core. It is running the Hyper-V role with containers and this is all it does. Now I have 10 VMs with a combined RAM allocation of 28GB and the server as 40GB installed.

For the life of me I cannot see or understand how the host is using all the remaining RAM it's madness. Can some please help me to understand and reduce the overhead for the host server?

I though it might be dynamic allocation of RAM so I have changed 8 servers to static RAM, basically turning off dynamic RAM and so the RAM cannot flux. I was hoping that this will reduce the overhead as there is nothing to save for the reserve. This has been to no avail. I'm at a loss.

I have only two servers using dynamic ram with start-up 2GB min 1GB and Max 2GB so can never go over the threshold of 2GB of Ram as predefined by the Max allocation and I kept these like this to see if it has in impact and the answer is no.

CPU utilization is basically 0% with all VM's allocated with 2 cores and the CPUs never touch 5%, sweet it's just this blasted RAM at 100%

Physical Server: image below for specs (using Windows Admin Centre)
[image: Windows Admin Centre Displaying 100% RAM usage on host server]

Comment: does this install on the host or any computer use the hostname to connect and a link would be nice, thanks. update this run on the machine in question with a GUI so i'm using server core as specified so cannot use as not GUI will display on the server core host server and you cannot use it to connect to another computer. uhhhmm

Comment: Your question is attracting close votes, I think this is because there is a lot of pretty simple debugging information missing. Can you [edit] your question to include this information? Have you checked the task manager (sorted by memory usage)? Do you have SQL Server installed? Have you run a malware sweep?